# Should I purge python from my machine and reinstall everything through conda and do all my projects in virtual environments?

Tags: python

I'm coming to python from R, where package management is really simple.  As I learn python (though a lot of googling), I see recommendations about virtual environments (which I never set up), and conda over pip for package management (I did pip because it seemed easier).

So now I've got a bunch of libraries installed globally, spyder is broken after a routine ubuntu ubdate ([this problem](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/7433), I think, which is solved using conda), and I am contemplating starting from scratch.  But I know that lots of other system programs depend on python, so I can't just nuke it and start over like I would with R.

So:

1. Is my instinct correct?  Should I "start fresh" with my python environment?
2. How do I do this in a way that won't disrupt other processes on my machine?

I know that python 2.7 exists on my machine, and I assume that it does something consequential.  I use python 3 for manipulating and analyzing data.  I think that this is relevant, but I am not sure how.

Comment: You shouldn't touch your system Python, ideally. You should definitely not remove it.

Comment: Too late to not touch it. What now?

Comment: Virtual environments will enable you to manage your project without affecting your machine globally, and you can choose a package manager within this environment.

Comment: @Matts you're saying that I don't need to go back and undo anything? Just ignore the global stuff and stop touching it?

Comment: If there's no problem, you can create a virtualenv, and work within that environment. I don't know what you've changed on your system, so I can't really comment on that.

Comment: *Just definitely don't remove it*. Use a fresh python installation, or even the anaconda/conda distribution, and start using environments